# help me to evaluate these integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the value of $$\int\frac{x}{x^2-x+1} dx$$ and $$\int\frac{1}{x^2-x+1} dx$$ This was not the original question. Original question was tougher and I have simplified that to these two integrals. I am having a hard time evaluating these two integrals but what I know is that, in these two integrals there is arctan occurring in a term of both integrals. Maybe we have to do some operations in the numerators?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The original question was: $$\int\frac{3x}{x^3+1}dx$$

EDIT: $$\begin{align}\int\frac{3x}{x^3+1}dx&=3\int\frac{x}{x^3+1}dx\\&=3\int\frac{x+1}{3x^2-3x+3}dx - 3\int\frac{1}{3x+3}dx\\&=\int\frac{x+1}{x^2-x+1}dx - \int\frac{1}{x+1}dx\end{align}$$
The value of last integral is $\ln|x+1|$ so we will consider it later. We will only consider the first integral now and we can write that as:
$$\int\frac{x}{x^2-x+1}dx + \int\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx$$ after this I am stuck.

Comment: Unfair as it may seem, this question may not get a good reception as long as your reducing another problem to these isn't shown. Anyway, substituting $y=\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}$ will help because then $\frac{dx}{x^2-x+1}\propto\frac{dy}{y^2+1}$.

Comment: for first, use $x^2 - x + 1 = t$ and for second, use partial fractions

Comment: i dont know partial fractions

Comment: i can add original question though

Comment: @sku what are partial fractions

Comment: @LOL On this site, make sure you use formal language.

Comment: Hey @LOL can you edit your question to add your simplification of the original integral?

Comment: @MathGeek okay i edited my message

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes but it is quite big so i need some minutes

Comment: @insipidintegrator added

Comment: @J.G. can you pls elaborate

Comment: It amounts to $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{x^2-x+1},\,\frac{d}{dx}\frac12\ln(x^2-x+1)=\frac{x-1/2}{x^2-x+1}$.

Comment: @user2661923 pls type your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Integral No. 1

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2-x+1}= \int \frac{dx}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$ Substitute $x-\frac12=t$ so $du = dt$. The integral becomes $$\int \frac{dt}{(t^2+\frac34)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\frac{t}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}+c= \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\frac{2(x-\frac12)}{\sqrt3}+c = \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}+c .$$

## Integral No. 2

$$\int \frac{xdx}{x^2-x+1}= \int \frac{x-\frac12+\frac12}{x^2-x+1}dx= \int \frac{x-\frac12+\frac12}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}dx$$$$= \int \frac{x-\frac12}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}dx+ \int \frac{\frac12}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34} dx $$ Now the second part is half of the first integral itself. For the first part, substitute $(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34=m$ and you should be able to finish it.

EDIT: After the m substitution, $2(x-\frac12)dx=dm$ so $(x-\frac12)dx=\frac{dm}{2}$. So the integral now is : $$\int \frac{dm}{2m}=\frac 12 \ln m + c=\frac12\ln(x^2-x+1)+c.$$

Comment: I cannot understand how the **m** substitution will work. Pls clarify.

Comment: @LOL edited to add.

Answer (score 2):

For the second one: A common method would be: complete the square in the denominator...
$$
x^2-x+1 = x^2 - x + \frac14+\frac34
=\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34
$$
Substitute $x-\frac12 = y$.
$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}\;dx = \int\frac{1}{y^2+(\sqrt{3}/2)^2}\;dy
$$
recognize an arctangent integral
$$
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}y\right)+C
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C
$$

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is the second integral since the first one has the form
\begin{align}
\int{{x \over x^2-x+1}dx} & = \int{{x-{1 \over 2} \over x^2-x+1}dx}+{1 \over 2}\int{{1 \over x^2-x+1}dx} \\
& = {1 \over 2}\int{{1 \over x^2-x+1}d(x^2-x+1)}+{1 \over 2}\int{{1 \over x^2-x+1}dx} \\
& = {1 \over 2}\bigg(\log{(x^2-x+1)}+\int{{1 \over x^2-x+1}dx}\bigg)
\end{align}
To solve the second one, we notice $\int{{1 \over y^2+1}dy}=\int{{1 \over \tan^2{\theta}+1}d\tan{\theta}}=\int{{1 \over \sec^2{\theta}}\sec^2{\theta}d\theta}=\theta=\arctan{y}$. Therefore, it is easy with
\begin{align}
\int{{1 \over x^2-x+1}dx} & = \int{{1 \over (x-{1 \over 2})^2+{3 \over 4}}d(x-{1 \over 2})} \\
& = \sqrt{4 \over 3}\int{{1 \over \bigg(\sqrt{4 \over 3}(x-{1 \over 2})\bigg)^2+1}d\bigg(\sqrt{4 \over 3}(x-{1 \over 2})}\bigg) \\
& = \sqrt{4 \over 3}\arctan{\bigg(\sqrt{4 \over 3}(x-{1 \over 2})\bigg)}
\end{align}

Comment: how did you arrive to the second step of your answer? Where you have written $d(x^2-x+1)$, how did you write that

Comment: Since $(x-{1 \over 2})dx={1 \over 2}d(x^2-x)={1 \over 2}d(x^2-x+1)$, we have the answer. It is sometimes useful to consider the infinitesimal quantity $f'(x)dx=df(x)$, which results from ${df(x) \over dx}=f'(x)$, when we solve the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Response transferred from the comments, per the request of the original poster.

---

Your 2nd question broaches an underlying issue.  My Calculus book specifies that for rational functions :

$$\int \mathbf{R}\left[x, \sqrt{a^2 + (cx + d)^2}\right] ~dx,$$

you use the substitution

$$~(cx + d) = a\tan(t).~$$

$$x^2 - x + 1 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2 + \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2.$$

The point of this response is that your Calculus teacher/book/class should **never** ask you to re-invent the wheel.  This type of formula should be **handed to you** in advance of your trying to attack such a problem.  If that is not the case, you are using/in the wrong book/class/teacher.

Comment: “…should never ask you to re-invent the wheel…” why is this? I mean, won’t that be spoonfeeding the students and blocking critical thinking?

Comment: @insipidintegrator The critical thinking is nourished by presenting problems that have variations in them, so that the student is required to use the tools in creative ways.  Personally, I regard myself as reasonably adept at Math.  If I was assigned such a problem, without first being spoon fed the formula, I could easily spend over $(10)$ hours on the problem and still fail to solve it.  This would create a negative emotional experience which would retard my energetically trying to become fluent in the *foreign language* represented by this area of Math.  ...see next comment

Comment: @insipidintegrator I agree that it is a judgement call, how much intuition stretching / creative leaps are required as the student tries to move from the provided *tools* to the specific problem's solution.  In this case, I think that the intuition-stetching/distance-to-leap is too far to (in general) have a positive effect on (what is in effect) a foreign language student.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. By the way, would you regard trying to find a new(to them, not necessarily to the math community) proof of the Pythagoras or the Quadratic Reciprocity, of which there exist a huge number of proofs, also a futile exercise? Just asking. I have understood your stance. Yeah, I get it, that that would be equivalent to asking one to make intellectual leaps on par with the greatest mathematicians.

Comment: @insipidintegrator No.  However, I would question whether **assigning** to an *undergraduate* Math student the task of attacking one of those problems is highly questionable.  However, you have the two exceptions of [1] For graduate students, things are entirely different, as independent research is part of their job. [2] If the undergraduate student poses the challenge to himself, that is entirely different.  Then, he is voluntarily trying to *scale a high wall*, and has the option to resign the task at any time, without penalty.  This is not a bad situation, even for an undergraduate.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user2661923 actually it was given in my book, i was dumb for not remember it